# Are autotools and cmake intended to be used by application users or developers?

Tags: software-installation

If I am correct, `autotools` and `cmake` are different tools to automatically generate configure and Makefiles from source code.

During installation, I often download the configure and Makefiles as a user, but I heard that some users (like users of VTK, ITK, ...) have to use `cmake` or `autoconfig` and `automake`.

Are developers supposed to provide configure and Makefiles ready and available to users?
If yes: Are `cmake` and `autoconfig` supposed to be used by developers during software distribution?

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "supposed to" implies that there is some sort of rule about how a developer or user is expected to behave.  That's not really reasonable. :-)

People who distribute software can take the packaging as far as they choose to -- their time is their time, after all.  "Users" come in all flavors -- that could be anyone from a complete neophyte to a seasoned administrator.

Speaking as a seasoned administrator, I would say that I greatly appreciate packagers who take the time to either get their software included into popular distributions or build good cross-platform installation.  Often the cross-platform installation will come in the form of a tarball that uses the Gnu toolchain so that all I have to do in order to get things installed is "1. configure; 2. make; 3. make install".

For the optimal experience it seems to me that's where developers should put their goals -- to produce a tarball that uses the cross-platform Gnu toolchain to enable the configure/make/make-install sequence.  If a developer takes it that far, then the people who make distributions have a really easy way of both getting packages built for their distribution and also (importantly) feeding fixes back up to the developer to improve the install-from-tarball packaging the developer maintains.

As an admin, I always default to using the packages included in my distribution.  This way I benefit from the bugfixes and security updates provided later by the distribution vendor.  I only go out to source code tarball as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks. What benefits does leaving autoconfig/automake/cmake to users have, compared to that users only have to run configure/make/make install?

Comment: Users of distributions should default to only getting software from their distributions -- ie if you are on RHEL, you should only get software from RHEL, and it should be sort of a big deal for you to go off the reservation by compiling from source.  I say that because software needs updates and audits and all kinds of important things over time, and doing a good job of maintaining that stuff over the life of an application is beyond most "users", even the professional sysadmins paid by enterprises (because that's not a good use of their time vs a paid RHEL subscription).

Comment: Oops -- meant to add more there, didn't realize there was a character limit or a time limit for revising edits. :-)  Aren't those tools really more attuned to developers?  I typically hope for the configure command as the beginning of my hands on a package if it didn't come from my vendor -- that's become a sort of de facto standard, so my experience carries over from one installation process to the next.